# Solving Coupled equations

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I need to solve a coupled equation and basically I am completely stuck on how to proceed. 
The equations are
$$
   a = u_\pm + \frac{i}{b}\cdot\frac{u_+ - u_-}{\sqrt{u_{\pm}^2-1}}
$$
and
$$
N_\pm(a) = Re(u_\pm\sqrt{u^2_\pm-1})
$$
so my aim is to get N as a function of u, everything's constant except for the u's.
It would be great if you could help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: What are these symbols? Which are constants, which are indeterminates?

Comment: a and b are constants u are indeterminates

Comment: And what about $u_+, u_-, u_{\pm}, i, E, N, Re$? What are they? complex numbers, functions, ... ? You should say what they are, because nothing is clear in this question.

Comment: u+ and u- are complex and dependent on a, as is N. i the imaginary unit,  Re is the real part of the brackets, N is a real function.